# Using variable as Boolean in conditional statement in Dart

Tags: dart, boolean-expression

I'm learning Dart after coming from Python and I wanted to know what is the closest Dart has to using a non-Boolean variable as a Boolean in conditional statements. Like using a string where an empty string is `false` and a non-empty string is `true`.

For example, in Python:

```
name = 'Yes'

print('True' if name else 'False') // 'True'

name2 = ''

print('True' if name else 'False') // 'False'
```

Does Dart have something similar without having to convert the variable to a Boolean statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart has *no* affordance for using non-boolean values in tests. None, whatsoever. Can't be done.

The only expressions allowed in a test positions are those with static type:

- `bool`
- `dynamic` (which is implicitly downcast to `bool` as if followed by `as bool`, which throws at runtime if it's not actually a `bool`.)
- `Never`, which always throws before producing a value.

The `bool` type, in non-null-safe code can evaluate to `null`. The test also throws at runtime if that happens.

So, for any test, if the test expression does not evaluate to a `bool`, it throws. You can only branch on an actual `bool` `true` or `false`.

If you have a value where you want to treat both `null` and empty as false, I'd do: `if (value?.isEmpty ?? false) ...`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such code will even compile. Type checking in `dart` tends to be very strict, and whenever the compile tries to evaluate a condition which is not of type `bool` it raises an error.
For example, the following won't compile:

```
final String value = "truthyValue" ? "truth" : "dare";
```

Instead, `dart` offers the `isNonEmpty` and `isEmpty` methods on many built in types such as strings, different containers so on, so you could do something like `someString.isNotEmpty ? "good" : "bad";`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write extension on any types, if you need to handle the specific values such as '0' or '00000'. I like it very much because it is handy for any parsing and if you name it well it is readable.

```
extension BoolTest on String? {
  bool get toBool {
    if (this == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

then you simply use it like this:

```
String? a = 'hello';
String? b;
print(a.toBool);      // true
print(b.toBool);      // false
print('hello'.toBool) // true
```

Have a look at: https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods